# Should it be possible to move a comment from an answer to the OP?

Tags: feature-request

I've come across these situations while reviewing occasionally. As an example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34037270/336648) *(assuming it has not been deleted by the time you read this).

The answer here should clearly be a comment on the original question, so I would recommend it be deleted. There may however be several useful comments below this answer, which may be lost if the answer is deleted.

So my question: Would it be useful to add a feature where a comment could be moved from an answer, and up to the original question? I realize that moving things around like this may complicate things if not used with care, but I think it's a shame if useful content is lost unnecessarily.

Perhaps it could be limited to moderators, with an option added to the list of flagging options? Something like *"I'm flagging this comment because I think it would be more useful under the main question"*.